# SDL_Init seems to be causing my program to crash

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl-2

So, I'm currently trying to build an app using the SDL library. This is what my Main.cpp file looks like

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED 
#include <SDL.h>  

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{     
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);     
    return 0; 
}
```

And this is what my Makefile looks like:

```
build:     
    g++ -w -std=c++2a \     
    ./src/*.cpp \     
    -o game \     
    -I ./lib/lua \     
    -I "C:\SDL2\include" \     
    -L ./lib/lua \     
    -L "C:\SDL2\lib" \     
    -llua \     
    -lSDL2 \     
    -lSDL2main \     
    -lSDL2_image \     
    -lSDL2_ttf \     
    -lSDL2_mixer \  
clean:     
    del game.exe  
run:     
    game
```

I'm not sure if you guys needed to see the Makefile, but there it is just incase. Just for clarity, I'm using VSCode and compiling with g++ (complements of MinGW) on Windows 10. The reason for the `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` is because if I don't do that, I get a linker error saying `undefined reference to WinMain@16` when I try to build. Anyways, when I run "mingw32-make build", the build process seems to go off with no problem (as in, I don't get any errors). But, when I try to run the program with "mingw32-make run", I get the following error:

```
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'run' failed 
mingw32-make: *** [run] Error -1073741515
```

The weird part is that this only occurs when I have the `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);` statement. If I exclude that (but still `#include <SDL.h>` and `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED`) the build and run seem to work just fine. But, it gets even weirder because at some point I was getting some warning from mingw32-make refusing to run the "run" recipe because of "potentially unwanted or harmful software associated with this program" or something like that. I haven't been able to replicate this warning so I have no clue what was going on. I just deleted all the SDL files and redownloaded them because I thought maybe I just got some corrupted files, but I keep getting the same error from the makefile. When I run the "game.exe" file directly from the console I get nothing, which I can only assume means that the program is crashing. To confirm this, I included a print statement in the program to see if I could get any output to the console, but still nothing :/ so I'm positive the program is just crashing.

Comment: Turn off your anti virus software?

Comment: The first two questions under the [SDL FAQ miscellaneous](http://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows#Miscellaneous) section seem relavent. If I'm reading that right you should remove `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` and include the library `-lmingw32`

Comment: Just saying, this is not the intended way of using SDL2. The intended way would be removing `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` and replacing `-lSDL2` `-lSDL2main` with `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2` (in this order). Not sure if it's the source of the problem though. What does your debugger say?

Comment: HolyBlackCat, you're a wizard. Could you explain to me why that specific order works? Or why the order even matters in the first place? And where could I find more information on this topic? And I can't stress this enough, thank you!